# Is a compilers course or a databases course more relevant for robotics engineering?

Tags: software

I am trying to decide between taking a compilers and interpreters course where we create an OpenGL shader compiler and a databases course. My aim is to go into robotics engineering and I am wondering which of these courses would provide the most benefit for that career path?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* ce1, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, & they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation & are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

Answer (score 1):

I think the database course is much more related to robotics than the compiler course. Almost every robot needs some kind of long term memory to store tasks, parameters or facts it learned about objects, itself or the environment. Compiler design for shaders is a much smaller niche and could maybe help you if you want to go into computer vision or visualization, but for a general roboticist I'd definitely go for the database course.

Comment: the compilers and interpreters course produces an OpenGL shader compiler as the final product, but it would teach you how to write a specialized robot language compiler or interpreter

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And this is nothing a robotics engineer will most likely do in her career.